# Explanation on Rspec + Devise::TestHelpers type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, devise

I'm using [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) to test my application and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for my authentication solution.

As a lot of us, I ended up with the common error : [`undefined method authenticate' for nil:NilClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308094/all-ruby-tests-raising-undefined-method-authenticate-for-nilnilclass) which I resolved partially by adding this line as suggested in the [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers) :

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
```

The error goes away for controller's tests, but it was still there for my view's tests. I finally completely resolved it by adding :

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view
```

But I'm not sure if it's the right things to do since I've never seen it before anywhere.

Also, can we include it for every type like `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :all` ?

Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a module in all examples by not specifying `type`.

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers
```

If your views are using Devise's helpers, like `current_user` or `user_signed_in?`, including `TestHelpers` in their specs is reasonable. Though architecturally, you might want to consider assigning things like `@user = current_user` in your controller so you can decouple the views from authentication.